# Year is out of valid range: 1400...10000

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, datetime

I'm attempting to use boost::date_time to parse a date string (obtained from the Twitter API) into a ptime object. An example of the date format is:

```
Thu Mar 24 16:12:42 +0000 2011
```

No matter what I do though, I get a "Year is out of valid range" exception while trying to parse the string. The date format looks correct to me, here is the code:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime created_time;
std::stringstream ss(created_string);
ss.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit); //Turn on exceptions
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%a %b %d %T %q %Y")));
ss >> created_time;
```

In the above code "created_string" contains the above date. Have I made a mistake in the format string?

Comment: One thing's for sure, you've created a memory leak by using `new` inside a function call. Are you more experienced with Java or C#?

Comment: Yeah don't worry I know about that, I've just been rearranging the code trying to get it to work, I'll fix it up when I get the date parsing :)  EDIT: Actually, I don't think it does result in a leak... the time_input_facet is refcounted unless you pass 1 as the second optional constructor arg.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked, passing a pointer to a time_input_facet on the stack results in a crash when the locale is destroyed (unless you pass 1 to the constructor which disables the refcounting). So the above code doesn't leak (even though it looks like it should :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `%T` and `%q` are output-online format flags.

To demonstrate that, change your format to `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"` and your program will run as described.

As for time zone input, it is a bit more complex, you may have to pre-process the string to change +0000 to [posix time zone format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.posix_time_zone) first.

EDIT: for example you could do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
int main()
{
        //std::string created_string = "Thu Mar 24 16:12:42 +0000 2011";
        // write your own function to search and replace +0000 with GMT+00:00
        std::string created_string = "Thu Mar 24 16:12:42 GMT+00:00 2011";

        boost::local_time::local_date_time created_time(boost::local_time::not_a_date_time);
        std::stringstream ss(created_string);
        ss.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(),
                 new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %ZP %Y")));
        ss >> created_time;
        std::cout << created_time << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, typically I'd tried with both %H:%M:%S and +0000 individually, but not at the same time! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags), `%T` is not usable for input at this time since its followed by a `!` in the chart.  I can't test it right now, but I'm suspecting that to be your problem.

Edit:

`%q` is also an output only flag as pointed out in the comments below.

Comment: @Kazade, `%q` is also stated to be "output only" in the description. I suspect that's the real problem.

Comment: Yea, I was just going to comment on the `%q` as well.  It doesn't have the nice little `!` to make it immediately obvious :)